# Jekyll Podcast RSS file problems

Tags: rss, jekyll, podcast

I'm setting up a podcast with Jekyll and the rss file isn't taking the config.yml files information. site, title, author, etc... Does anyone have any experience with podcasting and Jekyll and setting up an rss feed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [itunes.rss](https://github.com/writethedocspodcast/writethedocspodcast.github.io/blob/master/itunes.rss) file in [this repo](https://github.com/writethedocspodcast/writethedocspodcast.github.io). The rendered file is here: http://podcast.writethedocs.org/itunes.rss. This validates fine in http://castfeedvalidator.com/.

Many values for the feed are set in the config file. If your feed isn't taking the values, have you restarted the Jekyll server since you have changed any of the config's values?

Comment: I added the values manually for the site. For some reason the iTunes section is pulling from the config.yml file. It works now but it is a bit perplexing...